# Flutter & OneSignal: Updating UI with background push notifications (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, push-notification, flutter-method-channel

I have a flutter app that has push notifications functionality. For managing push notifications I'm using one signal package. So far it works pretty well, but I found myself strugling with handling notifications when I recieve them in the background. I need it because I want to update list of notifications that user see in the app each time new notification received. One signal doesn't have it built in and I tried to add it myself.

I've tried to adjust swift code for this, and because of the lack of experience of working with swift it's a bit challenging for me. I've tried to add this function - `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` to the `AppDelegate` because according to the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application) it should be triggered when notification is received either in foreground or background mode. I've tried to debug it and put some break points and prints but it was never triggered. I also tried to use `NotificationServiceExtension` to make it work, and it looks like `didReceive(_:withContentHandler:)` function here is trigerred as it should, but the problem is that because it's outside of the `AppDelegate` I'm not sure how I can pass infromation about notification from the swift to flutter because I don't know how to get binaryMessenger here

So I'd like to clarify a few things:

1. Is it possible to somehow send data from `NotificationServiceExtension` to `AppDelegate`? Because I've seen some articles and I'm not sure about it because it seems they're running in different containers
2. Maybe it would be possible to send data directly from `NotificationServiceExtension` directly to the flutter side?
3. Is there other approaches how I could catch notifications and send them directly to the flutter side?

Below the swift code that I've used:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    var flutterChannel: FlutterMethodChannel!
    
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        let binaryMessenger = (window.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController).binaryMessenger
        flutterChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "my.notification", binaryMessenger: binaryMessenger)

        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        self.flutterChannel.invokeMethod("getNotification", arguments: "Notification from push")
    }
}
```

Comment: First, I would say that it is a mistake to try and use notifications to deliver data to your app. That isn't really their purpose. If you send a silent notification (`content-available:1`) it may be delivered to your app delegate when it is in the background, but this type of notification is rate limited, so not all may be delivered. A notification extension is intended to let you modify the content of a notification before it is show. You could possibly use an app group to share a file between your  extension and your app

Comment: An overall more reliable approach is to have your app check fetch data from the server when it returns to the foreground.

Comment: @Paulw11. Thank you for the comment. I'd like to clarify that I don't use notification as a way to deliver data to the app, because it's clear that some user can just disable it and a notification won't be delivered. What I want is to make it more convinient for the user, so they don't need to refresh the page manually when new notification is arrived. I also aware that I can catch events when users click on notification and open the app. But I was thinking to try to handle it without any user interaction

Comment: And your advice about fetching data from the server when app returns to the foreground might help me to achieve what I'm trying to implement. Thank you